# C++ Basic while loop with keystroke to exit

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and this is my second assignment.  It is supposed to accept input from user until they enter the `|` to exit the program. What have I done wrong?

```
int main()

    int i = 0;
    char a = 0;
        while ( a != "|" ){  //has also told me this is an
                             // invalid operator
    int numeric;
    cout << "Give character: ";
    cin >> a ;
    cout << "Its ascii value is: " << (int) a << endl;
    ++i;

    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
2   IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("char" and "const char *")
```

Comment: Use `'`s instead of `"`s

Comment: Enclosing stuff inside `"`s results in a string literal, which is of type `const char *`. This is a pointer to an array of characters. You can't compare a single char to an array of characters. Use `|`.

Comment: @BWG: *"string literal, which is of type `const char *`"* - a string literal is actually an array of `const char`, *not* a `const char*`; the confusion's not uncommon given the standard conversion to `const char*` kicks in quite readily.  The difference is significant: e.g. for `sizeof` and when passing it to `template <size_t N> void f(char (&s)[N]);`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `"|"`.  Put `'|'` instead.  You want to compare a `char` to a `char`, NOT compare a `char` to a `char*`.

Comment: *"NOT compare a `char` to a `char*`"* - my comment to BWG under the question is relevant here too.

Answer (score 1):

You shall use `while ( a != '|' )` instead

`'|'` is a character and `"|"` is a string which has only 1 character

Comment: *"`"|"` is a string which has only 1 character"* - that's debatable... `"|"` is a string literal composed of '|' and NUL / '\0', which is '|' with a terminating sentinel in ASCIIZ encoding....

Comment: @TonyD You are right. LOL. Let's say "one valid character"